# drupal recrutement module

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

HI all,
i'm looking for a drupal module that allows users to :
post jobs offers,
apply for jobs,
notify users by email for new job offers,..
any advises please ?
i took a look at job search module but didn't find a tutorial to explain how to :(
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal doesn't usually have single modules that integrate all of the functions for specific domains. Rather modules are usually multi-purpose and integrate well with each other so that many different requirements can be built.

I would guess that the following modules will be a good way to start building your recruitment site.

- CCK
- View
- Rules
- Panels (this may not be necessary)

Then you can create the content types you need, set up the permissions and define the views you want for the project to get what you want.

If you're looking for a single module that does everything, you're going to find yourself hard pressed to find one.

Comment: Not a problem. I'd also inform you that individual modules that might be more customized to what you want exist. I've never used those, but they might be worth looking into. The above modules are extremely flexible though, and between them can be used to achieve many great things.